# How to perform a pull request on another's pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

amalmagdy created a pull request and it is located at https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/pull/4361/commits/781e15b0dd89c205d3999fb844e984b695a36368

How can I perform a pull request on this pull request and make my own changes and allow them to be viewed by the community?

Comment: Since the pull request is from a branch on their repo, you would have to make a pull request on their repo.

Comment: @Ry-  Thanks, I've never done a pull request, and while a little off topic, hoping you can clarify something for me.  When creating a pull request, I click "New pull request", and then see a "Compare changes" page which shows "base:develop V <= compare: develop V".  There is a also a disabled "Create pull request" button.  To enable it, should I change "base: develop" or "compare: develop"?